# Instantiating object of a certain type

Tags: mesh, scripting

Complete beginner to Blender here so here goes an amateur question. I am a bit confused by the syntax of Blender and why you can't just create an instance of a mesh class and assign it a name. Anyway, I'm trying to create a human skeleton here what would I need to change in order to generate points into the scene to verify the locations. Currently, nothing appears on the scene which I assume is because I haven't selected a default mesh. How would I make these circles meshes?

````
    for index, landmark in enumerate(body_locs):
        mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new("{}_mesh".format(landmark))
        new_obj = bpy.data.objects.new('{}'.format(landmark), mesh)
        
        new_obj.location = (multiplier*x_pos.iloc[0,index + 1],multiplier*y_pos.iloc[0,index + 1],multiplier*z_pos.iloc[0,index + 1]) 
        print(new_obj.location)
        bpy.context.collection.objects.link(new_obj)
        ```
````

Comment: Could, ditch creating an empty mesh object and instead add empties `bpy.data.objects.new("Foo", None)`

Comment: How would that solve my problem though?

Comment: IMO it would _"generate points into the scene to verify the locations"_    May need to alter pre 2.8  `scene.objects.link` to `collections.objects.link` as in Q code if not already amended in dupe answers.

Comment: Thanks for you reply! They don't have any extent though. Also, would you then know how to connect some of these points with a straight line?